# Passing object list from the action to the render phase

Tags: java, spring, portlet

I'm working with spring MVC for portlets, and I found a problem.

I need to pass an Object List from the action phase to the render phase. I've tried to use the setRenderParameter, something like this:

```
actionresponse.setRenderParameter(String string, String[] strings);
actionresponse.setRenderParameter("myList",myList.toString());
```

Here we have the two methods:

```
@RequestMapping(params = ACTION_MYACTION)
public final void doAction(MyBean search, Errors errors, ActionRequest actionrequest, ActionResponse actionresponse) {
    String processName = UtilLog.getProcessName(CLASS_NAME, "doAction");
    successMessage.clear();
    justlist = null;

    validateBean(consulta, errors);

    if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
        try {

            mylist = myBpelImpl.getList(search);
    actionresponse.setRenderParameter("myList",myList.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(processName, ex);
            processError(actionrequest, null, ex);
        }
    }

    informSuccessMessage(actionrequest, errors, status);

}

@RequestMapping(params = ACTION_MYACTION)
public final String doRender(@ModelAttribute(value = "myBean") MyBean search, Errors errors, RenderRequest renderrequest) {

List<otherBean> mylist =   renderrequest.getParameter("myList");

    renderrequest.setAttribute(ServletContextKeys.SC_JUSTIFICANTE_LIST, myList);

    return ServletContextKeys.SC_CONSULTA_JUSTIFICANTES;

}
```

But this is not working, because in the render phase, it can't convert the String to my Object List. How could I do this..?

At first, I was using a  private List mylist at class level, but as far as I know, a controller is a singleton pattern, so we can't use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ActionRequest request object into your method signature like as following and add objects as attribute

```java
@ActionMapping(params = "doAction=searchDeviceResults")
public void searchResults(@ModelAttribute(value = "searchForm") SearchForm searchForm,
                          BindingResult bindingResult, 
                          ActionRequest request, 
                          ActionResponse response, 
                          SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    searchFormValidator.validate(searchForm, bindingResult);

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        response.setRenderParameter("doAction", "showDeviceResults");
        sessionStatus.setComplete();    
        List<AccountDetail> accList = accountService.getAccountDetail(adp);
        request.setAttribute("accountList", accList); // here we go
    }

}
```

Another important thing is to add below config tags in *portlet.xml* so without getting and putting again into render method your request attribute will be available on the *JSP*.

```xml
<container-runtime-option>
    <name>javax.portlet.actionScopedRequestAttributes</name>
    <value>true</value>
</container-runtime-option>
<container-runtime-option>
    <name>javax.portlet.renderHeaders</name>
    <value>true</value>
</container-runtime-option>
<container-runtime-option>
    <name>javax.portlet.escapeXml</name>
    <value>false</value>
</container-runtime-option>
```

Let me know if any issue occurs.

Comment: I'll try this approach, it's good to know. Just a few quick things...
Why do I need to configure two phase rendering with the renderHeaders param?
Isn't it false de default value of the escapeXml param..?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a good approach, if it worked. Because it doesn't (to me) as I'm using Liferay Portal 5.2.3:

"If your application requirement is to share the request attributes (String type or
complex objects) with subsequent render, event, and resource requests, and your
portlet container doesn’t support the actionScopedRequestAttributes option (as in
the case of Liferay Portal 5.2.3/6.x and Jetspeed 2.2), you should consider storing the
attributes in the PortletSession."

So I guess, my answer wasn't wrong at all...

Comment: i believe by default actionScopedRequestAttributes is false. another thing is if actionScopedRequestAttributes is false you have to read your request scope attributes in render method and put it again. i will still discourage storing values in session because they always travel with every page request and response though they are overhead to the system and may become the reason of bad performance and may need additional code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use JSR 286 Action-scoped Request Attributes. See http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363818/JSR-286-Portlets-Action-scoped-Request-Attributes.

Also, it might have been a typo but annotate your doAction with `@ActionMapping(params = ACTION_MYACTION)`

Comment: Actually it isn't a typo. I've defined in the controller class the ACTION_MYACTION, something like this:
private static final String ACTION_MYACTION = "action=" + ServletContextKeys.SC_MYACTION;

Comment: I found quite interesting the article, but it doesn't fix my problem. I'm already passing the values to the render phase, the thing is that I don't know how to convert a String to my Object List... 
There is no way to pass nothing but strings..?

Answer (score -2):

I've found the answer!

I need to use

```
PortletUtils.setSessionAttribute(actionrequest, "mylist", mylist);
```

instead of the actionresponse.setRenderParameter.

It works!

Comment: @Faisalkhan : Well, I know it's like you say, but in my concrete case it's an advantage to have this list in session. And of course, I take care of cleaning the session when it's needed. Anyway, thanks for the "help" and the negative vote...

Comment: @faisal-khan: By the way, still nobody gave other kind of solution to the problem...