# In Liferay 6.2 unable to pass object from class to jsp

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am trying to set an attribute of type list in a class and getting the attribute from the class to jsp by using following:

1. First setting the attribute by using

   actionRequest.setAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT",result);
2. For getting the object using the following

   request.getAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT");

But the above code always produces a `null`, why?

Comment: This is unfortunatelly not possible due to Portlet spec. Action request and render requests are independent servlet requests (there is usually a HTTP redirect between them). You need to use flash scope (i.e. temporary session attribute) or pass your value via render paramters (http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/StateAwareResponse.html#setRenderParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks for the comment can u please show me example of flash scope

Comment: setRenderParameter takes string as argument but i want to pass an object

Comment: There is another possibility -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416157/passing-object-list-from-the-action-to-the-render-phase . Will mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use renderRequest.getAttribute(--)

Please have below links for more details

[Liferay MVC Portlet Development](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/04/liferay-mvc-portlet-development.html)